# Why does my "next" property disappear in my JavaScript hash in Firefox 3.6

Tags: javascript, hash, object-literal

I'm creating a hash as an options object to pass to a jQuery plugin. One of the keys I need to use, as defined by the plugin, is `next`.

This works fine in Safari (so I assume Webkit in general) but in Firefox its removed, or ignored or something... its just not there. For example:

```
var opts = {
  "next": "some selector string",
  "prev": "some other selector string",
  "anotherOption": 1
};

console.log(opts);
```

Ouput:

```
anotherOption      1
prev               "some other selector string"
```

It's driving me crazy. What's more, there are tons of plugins and things that use this key name in some sort of options hash and I have never noticed this behavior before. Can anyone tell me what is going on here and how to work around it? (I've tried doing `opts.next = "something"` instead but it yields the same result).

It also not an issue with the surrounding code - I've typed the example (minus the console.log call) into my Firebug console and gotten the same result.

Comment: That's really interesting. I have no idea why it would do that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The *next* property does not print out in Firebug console, but it is indeed defined. This may be a problem with Firebug, not JS. Your code should still work.

```
>>> var v = {};
undefined
>>> v.next = 'foo';
"foo"
>>> v.prev = 'bar';
"bar"
>>> v
Object { prev="bar"}
>>> v.next
"foo"
```

Answer (score 4):

It's a [bug in Firefox](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=536137).

The bug does prevent Firebug from printing it, but the actual Object should still have the `next` property correctly defined.

Comment: Ahhhh ok. Well on one hand that is good... on the other hand it means i have more debugging of my actual code to do. At least im not goign crazy though... :-)